# Find scala-library.jar using CMake

Tags: scala, cmake

I want to find the location of scala-library.jar using CMake for my project. Can this be done in some way by using **execute_process** function in CMake to execute a scala code and get the location ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use `execute_process()` to call out to a shell to find `scala-library.jar`. You could also use CMake's [`FindJava.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindJava.html) and [`UseJava.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/UseJava.html) modules.

A bare bones `CMakeLists.txt` would look something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

find_package(Java COMPONENTS Runtime)
if(JAVA_FOUND)
    include(UseJava)
else()
    message(WARNING "Couldn't find Java")
endif()

find_jar(SCALA_JAR "scala-library")
message("scala-library.jar is at ${SCALA_JAR}")
```

In fact, on my debian system (after doing `apt-get install default-jre scala`) I get:

```
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Java: /usr/bin/java (found version "1.7.0.111") 
scala-library.jar is at /usr/share/java/scala-library.jar
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nega/foo
$
```

Read the documentation on [UseJava](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/UseJava.html) to see how to be more specific with your search with `find_jar()`.

Comment: Also just curious, can you also tell me how I could do this using execute_process() ?

Comment: A short example would be `execute_process(COMMAND find /usr/share -name scala-library.jar OUTPUT_VARIABLE SCALA_JAR)`. See the [documentation for `execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html), it's fairly complete.